# Regex should not change the case, but it does

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to build a highlight pipe in Angular. The Highlighting works but it also changes the case of the text to the entered case

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({
    name: 'highlight'
})

export class HighlightSearch implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(public sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

    transform(value: any, args: any): any {
        if (!args) {
            return value;
        }
        let re = new RegExp(args, 'ig');

        console.log(value, args);
        return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value.replace(re, `<span class="search-highlight">${args}</span>`));
    }
}
```

It should not change the case. This Pipe should simply return the value highlighted.

Comment: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers` : please provide a [mcve] reproducing your issue. You can use https://stackblitz.com

Comment: Please add your CSS for `.search-highlight`

Comment: I already did that :), but thanks